# Visual Studio 2017 Community syntax color highlighting not working for aspx files

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community, and it seems all aspx/asp files are not displaying syntax color highlighting. HTML, XML, even ASPX.CS....these all display the coloring just fine. Near the end of my rope....any suggestions how to activate coloring for these pages?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just upgraded and I am running into the same issue.